# What trait should I use for reading stream of bytes from files, TCP connections, simple strings...?

Tags: rust

I want to write some code that can read bytes from:

- stdin
- files
- a string
- TCP

and maybe others. What is the best way to do this in Rust?

I thought the `std::io::Read` trait was the way to go, but it seems to be lacking implementations for string at least (I just needed this particular one for testing - maybe I can use something else)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find it help to use the [`impl<'_> Read for &' [u8]` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#impl-Read-10) for reading bytes from a string. As the type indicates, you'll have to first convert your nice string into a slice of bytes. Here is a short, dumb example.

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{Error, Read, BufReader};

fn whoo<T: Read>(mut readable: T) {
    let mut buffer = [0; 10];
    readable.read(&mut buffer).expect("panic");
    println!("{:?}", buffer);
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    whoo("hello there".as_bytes());
    whoo("".as_bytes());

    let dict = File::open("/usr/share/dict/words")?;
    let reader = BufReader::new(dict);
    whoo(reader);

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Seems pretty obvious in hindsight ;) thanks for confirming `Read` is the trait for this.